# Какой вариант предложения лучше (полный или сокращенный)?

Tags: стилистика

Какой вариант предложения лучше (полный или сокращенный):
"Закон предусмотрел четыре ситуации, которые могут иметь место в практической деятельности органов расследования и которые могут привести к наделению лица статусом подозреваемого";
"Закон предусмотрел четыре ситуации, которые могут иметь место в практической деятельности органов расследования и привести к наделению лица статусом подозреваемого".

Answer (score 2):

Второй вариант  мне нравится больше. В СПП с двумя придаточными союзное слово (который) при однородном подчинении может быть одно. Так мы избегаем повтора.

Answer (score 1):

Да, второй вариант лучше. Надо избегать необоснованных повторов.

Answer (score 1):

Из двух зол я бы выбрал короткое.

**Но!**

По мне так два варианта несут (или могут нести) несколько разный смыл.
На бытовом языке союз "И" на самом деле означает "или" (тут нет противоречия, я знаю причину и при  случае готов обсудить, но сейчас не об этом). Юридические же формулировки зачастую приближаются к математическим, к ним должен быть и соответвующий подход.

Предложение "ситуации, которые могут иметь место... и которые могут привести..." вообще говоря надо понимать так, что в рассматриваемое множество ситуаций включаются ситуации, которые могут иметь место ИЛИ которые могут привести, т.е. обладают любым из оговоренных свойств, но не обязательно обоими.

Второй вариант предложения несет меньше двусмысленности, хотя в принципе и он её не лишён. Тем не менее, учитывая юридический характер ваших текстов (вы диплом пишете, нет?), я бы сформулировал предельно корректно:

***Из числа имеющих место в практической деятельности органов расследования Закон предусматривает четыре ситуации, которые приводят к наделению лица статусом подозреваемого***
(примерно, здесь тоже есть шероховатости, надо подумать).

Слова "которые могут" тут излишни, поскольку подобная модальность вообще не свойственна юридическим формулировкам. если уж без неё вообще никак, то следует использовать "при соблюдении соответвующих условий". Или "... таких-то условий". И еще. Если нет иного контекста, следует использовать настоящее время (часто даже ели закон уже утратил силу).

Answer (score 0):

Второй вариант лучше. Но я бы, не повторяя  союзное слово "который", во втором придаточном определительном повторила бы вспомогательный глагол в составном глагольном сказуемом "МОГУТ". Предложение выглядело бы так. Закон предусмотрел четыре ситуации, которые могут иметь место в практической деятельности органов расследования и МОГУТ привести к наделению лица статусом подозреваемого.